# Running current line *only* when using pipes in R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio, magrittr

Since I updated R Studio last month to version 1.0.136, the Run behavior seems different when using pipes.

Now, when I hit ctrl+enter on the first line of a multi-line pipe command, it runs through the whole section of code, right through to the end of the pipe. But often, I want to skip 1 or 2 lines in the section.

Am I missing something?
How can I run just a single line at a time, when using pipes?

Comment: What did you try based on [this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts) info?

Comment: Select the lines, then use ctrl+enter.

Comment: @jeroen-heier, I've read through that, and have tried CTRL+ENTER and ALT+ENTER;

Comment: @Axeman, thanks, I know that works, but if I wanted to run 6 out of 8 consecutive lines (skipping 2 non-consecutive lines within a block of code) it's frustrating. Select a block, run it, move to next block, select it, run it, move to next block...

Comment: Behaviour used to be that CTRL+ENTER would run _only_ the line the cursor was on, making this very easy.
I wonder why it has changed